# Is it possible to cause a function to return from within another function?

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to phrase this question exactly, but I'll give an example that explains what I am wondering about:

I have a function that is a permission check, let's call it A. And I call this function in another function, let's call B. If the permission check in A fails, I want function B to return. So what I would do is:

```
def permission_check_A(user):
    # check if user has permission
    return result_of_check

def another_function_B(user):
    used_passed_permission_check = permission_check_A(user)
    if not used_passed_permission_check:
        return
    # do other stuff if user passed
```

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to cause function B to return directly if the check in A fails. Something like:

```
def permission_check_A(user):
    # check if user has permission
    if not used_passed_permission_check:
        # cause the calling function B to return
        return
    return True

def another_function_B(user):
    permission_check_A(user)
    # do other stuff if user passed
```

I guess in the example I am giving here, it would make sense to use a decorator for this kind of functionality. But if the security check happens somewhere in the middle of function B, this would not work.

My main motivation to do this, is that I don't want to repeat the "if, return" lines over and over again in every function that calls function A.

Also I'm wondering if would even be a good idea if this was possible because it could make the code less readable (a reader would have to check function A to realize that function B could be forced to return when A is called). What are your thoughts?

Comment: No, it's not possible to make the calling function return. How do you know the calling function doesn't want to do something with the result, like display a message?

Comment: It isn't possible, but if function_B is going to call multiple other checks, you can iterate over a list of checks, and do whatever you want to do when one didn't pass/if all passed.

Comment: And why should it just be the immediate caller, and not its caller? How do you know what the calling tree is like?

Comment: The closest thing to this is raising an exception.

Comment: @Nik, This is one of the main reasons for exceptions. You can just declare what you want; the *callee* raises an exception if something non-desirable happens. Allowing might make it hard to reason, especially with recursion (similar to `goto` statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an exception

```
class PermissionError(Exception):
    pass

def permission_check_A(user):
    # check if user has permission
    if no_good():
        raise PermissionError("No permission")

def another_function_B(user):
    permission_check_A(user)
    # do other stuff if user passed
```

Raising the exception stops execution of the current function. If the next higher function doesn't have a try/except block active, it goes to the next higher function until its caught or the whole program exits.

A function could call many other functions within a single try/except. Or a top level function could catch all of the errors from a large swath of code.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where certain trivial conventions apply, you can achieve something like this with a **decorator**:

```
def check(p):
  def make(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def call(first,*a,**kw):
      if p(first): return f(first,*a,**kw)
    return call
  return make

@check(permission_check_A)
def another_function_B(user): …
```

This of course will not work if someone calls `another_function_B(user=…)` or if `another_function_B` adds parameters before `user`.